# Limitations XMLAgg or XMLStyle.createxml()

Tags: xml, oracle, oracle12c

i switched to Oracle 12g last month and now 1 query makes strange problems.
Its a really complicated Tablelayout, so just take the following tables for a test:

```
create table Order (
    id int not null,
    name varchar(255)
)

create table Position (
    id int not null,
    orderFk int not null,
    name varchar(255)
)

create table CNCData (
    id int not null,
    positionFk int not null,
    ncdata clob
)
```

CNCData.ncdata can be 4GB in size, so it will handly my generated Code which is really big sometimes.

When i execute this Query:

```
SELECT
  XmlElement("node", XMLAttributes('nc' AS "name", 'root' AS "value"),
    XmlElement("node", XMLAttributes('Order' AS "name", 'section' AS "value"), 
      XmlElement("node", XMLAttributes('OrderName' AS "name", o.name AS "value") ),
      XmlElement("node", XMLAttributes('OrderNr' AS "name", o.id AS "value") ),
      XmlElement("node", XMLAttributes('CreationDate'    AS "name", to_char(systimestamp ,'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS"Z"') AS "value") ),
      XMLAgg(
        XmlElement("node", XMLAttributes('Position' AS "name", 'section' AS "value"),
          XmlElement("node", XMLAttributes('PositionName' AS "name",  p.name AS "value") ),
          XmlElement("node", XMLAttributes('PositionNr' AS "name",  p.id AS "value") ),
          XMLAgg(
            XmlElement("nc_node", XMLTYPE.createxml(nc.ncdata))
              ) ORDER BY p.id
  ))))).getCLOBval() xml

FROM Order o
JOIN Position p ON o.id = p.orderFk
JOIN CNCData nc ON p.id = nc.positionFk
WHERE  o.id = 1234
GROUP BY p.name, p.id
```

I expect this output as CLOB:

```
<node name="nc" value="root">
  <node name="Order" value="section">
    <node name="OrderNr" value="1234" />
    <node name="OrderName" value="Testorder" />
    <node name="CreationDate" value="2019-04-24T10:20:31Z" />

    <node name="Position" value="section">
        <node name="PositionNr" value="1" />
        <node name="PositionName" value="pos1" />
        <nc_node>
            -- XML CLOB DATA
        </nc_node>
    </node> <!-- Position -->

    <node name="Position" value="section">
        <node name="PositionNr" value="2" />
        <node name="PositionName" value="pos2" />
        <nc_node>
            -- XML CLOB DATA
        </nc_node>
    </node> <!-- Position -->

    <node name="Position" value="section">
        <node name="PositionNr" value="3" />
        <node name="PositionName" value="pos3" />
        <nc_node>
            -- XML CLOB DATA
        </nc_node>
    </node> <!-- Position -->
  </node> <!-- order -->
</node> <!-- nc -->
```

But sometimes, Positions get completly lost when one of the ncdata columns are over 32KB. So instead of 3 Positions, i just have 2.

Am i right when i assume that XMLTYPE.createxml() has a limitation of 32KB? 
It worked in 11g without problems and i can´t find anything in the changelog of Oracle.

Is there a workaround i can use or do i have to query every position and add the ncdata code to my xml manually?

ps.: Sorry if you read it in an Answer, i was in the wrong Tab.

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes, there is a Problem and after the error ORA-22813 was thrown, we could search for ansers. In the Oracle Support Ticket 1456531.1 is the answer. After installing the Workaround Patch, we don´t have missing entrys in the XML Stream or the Exception with ORA-22813.